# Mutiple forms with Class Based View. How to show errors at the same page?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

## views.py

```
from forms.py import PersonCreateForm

class PersonCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Person
    form_class = PersonCreateForm
    template_name = "my_app/create_person.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        return redirect('/homepage/')


class PeopleListView(ListView):
        [...]
        context.update({
            'task_form': TaskCreateForm(),

        return context
```

In my template I just add in action url which handle PersonCreateView.

```
<form action="{% url 'people_create' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

When Form is valid then all data are saved without problems and it redirects me to '/homepage/.
But when my form is invalid then it redirects me to to `{% url 'people_create' %}` and shows errors at /homepage/people_create/

How can I avoid that? I want all errors show at same page without redirect.

Answer (score 4):

Handle the form on the same view you build it, otherwise the page will change. You may mix `django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin` into your `PeopleListView` so it has most of the features you need.

```
class PeopleListView(ModelFormMixin, ListView):
    success_url = '/homepage/'  # should use reverse() here

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # only add the form if it is not already given to us
        if not 'task_form' in kwargs:
            kwargs['task_form'] = self.get_form()
        return super(PeopleListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ListView won't have a post method, we define one
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)   # default behavior will save and redirect
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form) # default behavior has to be overridden (see below)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        # Whatever you wanna do. This example simply reloads the list
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        context = self.get_context_data(task_form=form)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

There, you have three code paths:

- Initial display will load the listview as usual, only an empty form will be added to the context.
- On submitting valid input, the `form_valid` method is invoked, which will redirect to `/homepage/`.
- On submitting invalid input, our overridden `form_invalid` method is invoked, which will render the page normally, except the form will contain the validation errors.

You may make the whole thing a bit more staightforward using a cached property for the form, but then you'd start working against Django's shipped views instead of with it, and might as well just use the basic `View` class and implement all logic by yourself. I'd stick with Django's views, but ymmv.

Comment: Notice: there were return statements missing, I just fixed them.

Comment: Sorry, for late response, but I got `AttributeError: 'PeopleListView' object has no attribute 'object'`